# Replacing a Len Gordon ff1094tc

Tags: relay, safety, control-system

I've got an air-button operated, 4 position relay unit, designed to safely operate the pump and air blower on a hot tub with multiple presses of an air switch mounted in the deck. Good unit, but it has some limitations, not the least of which is the cost.

I would like to design a circuit that can control 4 possible outputs, and that selects them in order with a push of a button. One press, circuit one is on, second press, circuit 2 on, 1 off, and so forth.

Any help out there? I have a feeling there is a simple relay configuration out there if I just ask the right question, or look in the right place.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a good fit here. You write: _"I would like to design a circuit "_. Well, not really. You want _someone_ to design it _for_ you. The problems I see with this is that no one can really know what you think is "safe enough", even though the circuit looks simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at binary counter and decoder logic ICs. The first two bits of a binary counter, routed to a 2-4 decoder, which then use transistor outputs to control relays, would be the general approach I would take.